# Add buttons to listItems in Extendscript

Tags: scripting, effects, extendscript

I'm trying to add a button to a list item in Extendscript.
Like this:
[image]

Sadly, I cant figure out how to achieve that. This is the way it currently is:
[image]
The user has to click on a list item and then on one of the three buttons to proceed.

This is my existing, working function.
I'm dynamically creating list items in a list box.

```
var writeMarkerListToWindow = function(list, listbox) {
  var listitem = [];

  for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    listbox.add("item", list[i].name).subItems[0].text = list[i].amount;
  }
}
```

The parameter "list" that I pass looks like this:
`list=[{"name":"start","amount":1},{"name":"stop","amount":2}]`

The parameter "listbox" obviously contains the Listbox like `[object ListBox]`.

I know it's possible to add an image file to a list item, which looks like this:
`listbox.items[i].image = File ("~/Desktop/image-destination.jpg")`

Sadly, I failed to use this syntax to create a button. None of the recommended sources for Extendscript Developement ([ScriptUi Classes](http://jongware.mit.edu/scriptuihtml/Sui/index_1.html), [Scripting Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf), [AE Enhancers](http://docs.aenhancers.com/), [Script UI](https://indd.adobe.com/view/a0207571-ff5b-4bbf-a540-07079bd21d75), Google) could help me.

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance!
Greets,
Simon

Comment: Did you take a look at Peter Kahrels Guide? [ScriptUI for dummies](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html) I never saw a Button embedded in a list item.

Comment: If you go for CEP panels instead of Script UI it can be done.

Comment: @fabianmoronzirfas, Thanks so much for your answer!
Yes, I did take a look in there — seems like I forgot to list it in my original post.
I haven't worked with CEP panels yet. Where would be a good place to start?

Comment: Actually that's achievable with ScriptUI but it's far from trivial. I would also tend to prefer CEP panels when it comes to such rich UX but CEP panels also bring their own lot of peculiarities. So it's up to you.

Comment: @SimonHeimbuchner Take a look into this [issue](https://github.com/ExtendScript/AMA/issues/13#issuecomment-331377970) for some links to get started.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you guys, I'll definitely look into CEP Panels!